# Saving plugin settings - ERROR: options page not found

Tags: php, plugin-development, options, settings-api

I've created a form for my plugin settings and set the action attribute of the form to "options.php" but when I submit the form I get "ERROR: options page not found."

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'create_menu');

function create_menu(){
    // add menu page
    add_menu_page(
        'Basic Plugin Menu Page', 
        'Bp Menu', 
        'manage_options', 
        'bp_menu', 
        'bp_menu_cb', 
        plugins_url('images/wordpress.png', __FILE__),
        76 );
    // add submenu page
    add_submenu_page(
        'bp_menu', 
        'Besic Plugin Submenu', 
        'Options', 
        'manage_options', 
        'bp_options', 
        'bp_options_cb' );
    add_action('admin_init', 'bp_register_settings_cb');
} // end add_menu
function bp_register_settings_cb(){
    // - register_setting( $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback );
    register_setting('bp-settings-group', 'bp_options', 'bp_options_sanitize');
} // enb bp_register_settings_cb

function bp_options_sanitize($input){
    $input['name'] = sanitize_text_field($input['name']);
    $input['email'] = sanitize_email($input['email']);
    $input['url'] = esc_url($input['url']);
    return $input;
} // end bp_options_sanitize

function bp_menu_cb(){ ?>
    <div id="wrap">
        <h2>Basic Plugin Settings</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="http://localhost/blogger.allaudin/wp-admin/options.php">
            <?php settings_fields('bp_settings_group'); ?>
            <?php $bp_options = get_option('bp_options') ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Name</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="bp_options[name]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($bp_options['name']) ?>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Email</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="bp_options[email]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($bp_options['email']); ?>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">URL</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="bp_options[url]" value="<?php echo esc_url($bp_options['url']) ?>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Save Changes" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php } // end bp_settings_page
```

Comment: In the function bp_menu_cb(), you have used settings_fields('bp_settings_group'); but it should be settings_fields('bp-settings-group'); because in the function bp_register_settings_cb() you have used "bp-settings-group" and not "bp_settings_group"

Answer (score 5):

> settings_fields('bp_settings_group');

`bp_settings_group`  should be changed to `bp-settings-group` 
to match.

`settings_fields( $option_group )`

`$option_group` should match the group name used in `register_setting()` i.e `bp-settings-group`.

check on codex [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/settings_fields).